# What is parmater code in graph access token facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get access token and here is my graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=...&client_id=1578635392400252&redirect_uri=http://example.com
```

I don't know what is the paramater "code", I reference this link and I can not see to explain this paramater https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#confirm

> When code is received, it has to be exchanged for an access token using an endpoint. The call will need to be server-to-server, since it involves your app secret. (Your app secret should never end up in client code.)

If you don't want the additional step to exchange the `code` for an `access token`, you can pass `response_type=token` as described in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#login

Question:

- Why don't you use the Javascript SDK?

Comment: Why don't you use the Javascript SDK?
Cuz popup was blocked by browser.

Comment: If you use the regular functionality, this shouldn't be the case. Otherwise a lot of people face these issues...